# Why might $B$ meson decays violate lepton universality?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, leptons

Scientists from various institutions have recently discovered that there might be a break in the application of the Standard Model, particularly with a fundamental principle called the [lepton universality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton) (lepton universality asserts that the interactions of leptons are the same, regardless of differences in masses and decay rates)

Their discovery comes from reviewing the data from three separate experiments — BaBar, LHCb and Belle — conducted in the United States, France/Switzerland, and Japan.
[Flavour-changing neutral currents making and breaking the standard model](https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v546/n7657/full/nature21721.html)

All three experiments revealed that the ratio of [B meson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_meson)
$B^0\to D^{(*)-}\tau^+\nu_\tau$ decays to $B^0\to D^{(*)-}\mu^+\nu_\mu$ decays may be larger than the standard model predicts

- How to make sure that they’re true?
- How this would play out?
- What confirmation of these results will mean (especially for long term)?
- What might cause this disagreement with the standard model?
- Why we’re seeing that lepton universality is not satisfied as the Standard Model claims?
- Do we need an entirely different model of elementary particle physics (to explain the peculiar behavior of the tau particle)?
- Could a change in one lepton affect the others (as these principles often correlate with one another)?

Comment: If you're talking about the R(D) and R(D*) anomalies, then you should know that it's not tau decays which disagree with the SM. It's the ratio of decays of B mesons to final states containing either a tau or a muon. Otherwise I don't know of any tau decay anomaly from LHCb/BaBar/Belle (I assume those are the experiments you mean, although LHCb is just on the French side of the border). Can you link to a news article or journal paper to confirm what you are asking about?

Comment: @dukwon [2 Accelerators Find Particles That May Break Known Laws of Physics](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/2-accelerators-find-particles-that-may-break-known-laws-of-physics1/)

Comment: Yeah, this is about R(D) and R(D*): the ratio of $B^0\to D^{(*)-}\tau^+\nu$ to $B^0\to D^{(*)-}\mu^+\nu$